# Why is the wrong value saved to the Database? Pulling hairs out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is driving me crazy.. I've used a debugger, I've restarted my computer, the mysql server, the console, terminal, everything.. Why is the wrong value being stored in the database?

Here are the lines that write.. there are a few setters before this..

```
msg.contentID = twt.attrs["id_str"]
msg.save
```

Here is the debugger output:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `messages` (`content`, `contentID`, `created_at`, `reply_to`, `sender_tid`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, 84756616506912768, '2012-01-27 00:01:58', 'ZachACole', 115192457, '2012-01-27 00:01:58', 32)
(0.5ms)  COMMIT
```

I immediately check the value in the database of contentID which should be '84756616506912768'.. and its not.. it's a different value, but its the same different value every time...  My message model has no validations on it.. as you can see here:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :tweet, order("contentID desc")
end
```

How do I debug something like this?

============

Update: The value I get everytime is:   2147483647

Comment: That's a very large digit. What is the value that is always being inserted instead? I'm guessing there's something going on because that size required to save that digit is much larger than the size of the column type. What is the column type?

Comment: Do you have any validations on the field in your database? What is the 'same value' you're getting every time?

Comment: @sscirrus I don't have have any validations on the database, as you can see from the Message model in the description...

Comment: @MrDanA how many digits can an integer hold?

Comment: Well it can depend on the language and the computer system, like 32-bit vs 64-bit. Check out this wiki page for some more information. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types

Comment: @Inc1982 - not sure you get what I mean. Your underlying database tables can still have column types (such as BIGINT) and other restrictions on the format of data (such as defaults, null requirements and so on) that goes into them. These are separate from class-level validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the column in the database a BIGINT?  A standard INT is too small to hold that number.

Comment: Oh :-|  I'll switch it up and report back

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, converted to a string and it works.  Althought MrDanA reported it first yours is an answer which I can accept.  Thanks!